# Adding google analytics code to all pages

Tags: google-analytics, statistics

I want to add google analytics code to all pages in my website. Can I place google analytics code in a JS file and mention the JS file in the header?

Comment: Depends which technology used for the website , as for ASP.NET you should look for .master Pages , as for ASP.NET MVC 3 _Layout.chtml like pages

Comment: I use simple HTML Pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in simple html pages there is no standard way to render script on each page , you can put ur GA code into separate .js file , and then include it on each Html page in header like

```
<head>
   <script src="#path-to-Code-with-GA" type="text/javascript" />
</head>
```

That's the only solution i can suggest :-(

Comment: This is my solution for HTML pages. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It would be easiest if your website was run in PHP or ASP.NET. 
If it's in PHP, place your Google Analytics code in a file, and title it however you'd like (e.g. analytics.php or analytics.html)

Then, right before the closing `</head>` tag in your document, place the following code:

```
<?php include 'analytics.php'; ?>
```

Otherwise, if you run your website through a CMS such as Wordpress, use a plugin like "All in one SEO pack", or if you want to hard code it in, go to the header file (header.php in Wordpress), and simply paste your code in the head section, or use the method listed above.